# material-ui button active style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to workout how I would have appbar buttons that link to components show a different style when active.

I should also note: this is a my first material-ui app and the docs are not so clear.

Basically I want an underline on the button that is active.

```
<Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={"/"}>Home</Button>
<Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={"/About"}>About</Button>
```

My full code.

```
import React, {useState } from 'react';
import { Link as Links } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
//import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    fab: {
      position: 'absolute',
      background:'red',
      bottom: theme.spacing(2),
      right: theme.spacing(2),
      "&:hover, &:focus":{
        background:'black',
      }
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      align:'center',
    },
  }));



  function Nav() {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [icon,setIcon] = useState(false)

    const fabIcon = {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 40,
    };


    const handleClick = e => { 
      setIcon(!icon)
      { icon ? document.getElementById("player").play() : document.getElementById("player").pause() }
    }


    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" align="center" className={classes.title}>
              News
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            <Button color="inherit" component={Links} to={"/"} linkButton={true}>Home</Button>
            <Button color="inherit" component={Links} to={"/about"}>About</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <AppBar position="static">
      </AppBar>
        <audio id="player">
                <source
                    src="https://samcloud.spacial.com/api/listen?sid=106487&m=sc&rid=184639"
                    type="audio/mpeg"
                />
            </audio>
            <Fab aria-label='test' className={classes.fab}>
            <i className='large material-icons' style={fabIcon} onClick={handleClick}>
            { icon ? 'play_circle_outline' : 'pause_circle_outline'}</i>
          </Fab>
      </div>
    );
  }


  export default class GrandChild extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("player").play() }, 3000);
    }

    value() {
      return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.input).value;
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div> 
          <Nav />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you just need to know how to customize the look of the button? Or are you also asking how to know which button is "active"?

Comment: @RyanCogswell how to set the button to active and customize the look.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had the same issue, and I solved it by using NavLink instead of Link from react-router-dom!

Example:

```
<Button
  className={classes.button}
  component={NavLink}
  to="/page-link"
>
```

This will add the class ".active" to active buttons.

Using material's makeStyles hook, you can then style the buttons with this class:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button: {
    "&.active": {
      background:'black',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: amazing solution ..Also does material UI provide anything elseto add active classes onclick .. or we have to do it with react ?

Comment: Haven't used Mui for a while now, but when I check their doc for "Selected menu" here https://mui.com/components/menus/ it seems that Mui just adds a class `.Mui-selected` for active menu items

Comment: btw @RussellHarrower if my initial answer solved your problem, I'd appreciate if you'd mark my answer as a solution :)

Comment: @codingforworlddomination Sadly this is not working in MUI5 :(

Comment: With Mui v5, wrap the NavLink in a Box and style with sx props:

<Box sx={{
      '& a.active > button': {
        color: theme => theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        bgcolor: theme => theme.palette.primary.main,
      }
    }}>
      <NavLink to={path} >
        <Button variant={"text"}>
          {text}
        </Button>
      </NavLink>
    </Box>

Comment: @VigneshS In v5 it's now "&:active" - posted an answer reflecting that.

Answer (score 2):

In MUI v5 you'd do:

```
'&:active': {
  backgroundColor: '#334252',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any third-party library like `Gatsby`, `React-router` then you should consider about this `Tabs`

[image]

#### Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: any;
  value: any;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: any) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[To master in Material UI Tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/)